# Is printing an array really O(n) instead of O(1)?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

According to this problem in Cracking The Coding Interview, printing an array is O(N), but I fail to see why it's not O(1). We have this code:

```
void permutation(String str) {
    permutation(str, "");
}

void permutation(String str, String prefix) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        for (int i= 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            String rem = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
            permutation(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

And in the explanation it says:

```
Executing line 7 takes 0( n) time since each character needs to be printed.
```

Why is this? As far as I know, printing is always O(1). When you print an array, it does it all at once, unless you use a for loop to print each individual character.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big-O notation does not say explicitly what it's measuring. You can talk about algorithms that take O(n) memory, or O(n) system calls. But the explanation here makes it clear that we're talking **O(n) time**. That is correct - O(1) system calls to print O(n) characters will take O(n) time.

Comment: Very true +1... Maybe some more research info for the topicstarter?  -> Java's `System.out.println` is most likely directly mapped to C/C++ `printf()` in the Java VM ... When researching `printf()` how a C/C++ compiler compiles it to machine code you will notice (note simplified after this) setting counters and decrementing (MOV/DEC) and looping (JMP) in the assembly code..  The longer the string the more assembly code is needed to loop that string so it is `O(n)` as more CPU instructions means more time to execute..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I'm fairly certain that it isn't, if only because `printf` is pretty slow. C is mostly compiled, but the `printf` format string is interpreted. `puts` would be the logical function to call, if not the OS directly.

Comment: Yes maybe is `puts` indeed the most logical call the Java VM would possible call  good point... Anyhow how knows for sure as the Java VM source code is not open source i believe?  Mine comment was more or less meant to give the topicstarter a (extra) better understanding why `System.out.println(prefix);` is `O(n)` time wise

Comment: *"Anyhow how knows for sure as the Java VM source code is not open source i believe?"* ... O i guess i spoke to soon as it seams in fact to be [open source](http://openjdk.java.net/) now . . .